# casperjs screenshot returning blank square boxes. Please tell me possible solution to get the character instead of boxes

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I am using CasperJS 1.1.0 with PhantomJs 2.0. I am using Linux server.
I have a script, trying to run and take screenshots.
This screenshot is fine for local server nor for live.
Screenshot of the site will look like this:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJe4L.png
```

So, instead of the actual letters, it renders square boxes.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
});
casper.options.waitTimeout = 40000;
casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1200, height: 768};
phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;
casper.start('http://domain.com/', function() {
    this.wait(5000, function () {
        this.echo(this.getTitle());
        this.capture("screenshot.png");
    });
});
casper.run(function () {
    this.exit(0);
});
```

Please tell me where i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [waitForSelector](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforselector) on the items that you're wanting screenshots of, rather than the 5 second hard wait. Consider adding

```
verbose: true
waitTimeout:20000
```

Which will give you 20 second wait limit, longer than the 5 seconds default. Then, instead of your current wait, use something like:

```
this.waitForSelector('img', function() {
    this.capture('test.png')
}
```

You can change the img selector to be something more specific, but waiting for the images themselves to load is a pretty certain way of making sure they will be captured. The reason we changed the timeout to 20 seconds is in case their site takes a little longer to load their images :)

Let me know if this doesn't help, happy to follow up. I will need examples of the site and the image you'd like though.

**EDIT**: Can confirm this works for me, let me know if it works for you.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: 'error',
  pageSettings: {
    loadImages: true,
    loadPlugins: true,
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11'
  },
  clientScripts: ['vendor/jquery.min.js', 'vendor/lodash.js'],
  viewportSize: {
    width: 1600,
    height:1000
  },
});

casper.start('http://dev.bunkerbradleycouture.com/')

casper.then(function() {
  this.waitForSelector('img', function() {
    this.capture('test.png')
  })
})

casper.run()
```

Comment: Above code is not working for me. still i am getting square boxes.

Comment: @user3335891 show me the page you want to scrape and I might be able to help more

Comment: I am scrapping this site dev.bunkerbradleycouture.com for automated test.

Comment: Can confirm this works, let me know if it works for you:

Comment: I am scrapping this site http://dev.bunkerbradleycouture.com/ for automated test.
But after scrapping showing like this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ethst.jpg

It is fine on my local machine but not for live server